# Async GORM or DataAccess and Sync code

Tags: micronaut

As I understand, Micronaut benefit from non-blocking i/o. In my project I need to use MySQL as data storage.

I would love to use GORM or a similar ORM to easy the access but they are blocking AFAIK.

Coming from Vertx, there is `executeBlocking` to execute in the thread pool blocks of sync code while not blocking the main loop.

So my question have two edges.

First, which ORM could I use to connect to MySQL, similar to GORM, but non blocking.

And Second, if there is a way, or benefit like in Vertx, to execute sync code keeping most part of the method async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any non-blocking ORMs and I don't whether it is even technically possible to implement all the features of an ORM in a non-blocking away. Take for example lazy loading an associations, if you access an association like `book.authors` you have to block to execute the query and load the association.

There are however non-blocking SQL drivers. You could try use the Vert.x driver https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client/java/ within Micronaut

As for running blocking operations, Micronaut has a simple strategy. If you return a reactive type is subscribes to the reactive type on the event loop, if you don't it runs the operation on a pre-configured I/O thread pool.

So simply returning `List<Book>` will run the operation on I/O thread pool unless you annotate the method with `@NonBlocking`

See https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#threadPools

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about something like @NonBlocking (which is missing from the user guide) but i suppose it will be easier to just return Single.just(value)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use [jasync-sql](https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql) (Disclaimer: I am working on it). It's not a full-blown ORM but it gives non-blocking capabilites an has async support.

It is used like this:

```
CompletableFuture<QueryResult> future =             
  connection.sendPreparedStatement("select * from table");
```

Hope that helps, if you need assistance please open an issue or take a look at the wiki: https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I'm explicitly scheduling the db call on `Schedulers.io()` which works well:

```
Maybe<User> get(String id) {
    return Maybe.fromCallable(() -> 
        query().select("*").where().eq("id", id)
            .findOne()
            .map(userDto -> User.from(userDto));
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

I use the Ebean ORM.